# Eloquent - concatenate columns with query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, laravel-5

I am running the following query to search for users by first or last name. I want to also search for the entire name if the full name is entered.

I'm using this which works well.

```
    $searchTerm = "Adam Pratt";

    return User::select(User::table().'.*'))
        ->where(function($query) use ($searchTerm){
            $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");
        })
        ->orLike(User::table().'.email',$searchTerm)
        ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Is there any better method at doing this, or cases where this isn't good?

Thanks.